# Splitting and aligning a slice/buffer into mutable chunks

Tags: rust

I'm looking to implement position_io2's `ReadAt` trait which provides a `&mut [u8]` buffer to write into against an API that can take parallel requests for certain fixed sized 512KB blocks.

The issue being that I can't guarantee that the position of the read will align to one of these block boundaries, therefore I would need to provide a slice of the full buffer to write into for each downloading closure.

The naive approach results in an error - `cannot borrow *buf as mutable more than once at a time`:

```
for SnapshotBlock { index, token } in blocks {
    let mut bufOffset: usize = ((index - start_block) * block_size) as usize - start_block_offset;
    let mut bufSize: usize = block_size as usize;

    block_contexts.push(BlockContext {
        output_buffer: &mut buf[bufOffset..(bufOffset+bufSize)],
        block_index: index,
        block_token: token,
        block_size,
    })
}
```

I can see a bunch of APIs to deal with static chunk sizes - e.g. `buf.as_chunks_mut()` but the closest dealing with my problem is `buf.align_to()` which returns three slices in a tuple, however that is only for types not large blocks like this.

Is there any libraries or other ways of providing a mutable slice to each downloading thread, or do I need to use unsafe code to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`chunks_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_mut) to divide the slice into contiguous blocks.